# How to crawl mobile website java?

Tags: java

I want to read mobile version of the website but my program reads the normal website.

I am using this property

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt)");
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Try reading m.example.com.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Just so you know typically you would provide more information on what you are doing and where you have been having problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision on which page to serve by the server is made based upon the "User-Agent" property of the request.

To get the mobile version of the page, take a look at [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) chrome dev article detailing chrome on android user agent strings, and set the "User-Agent" string in your header to be that of a mobile client; it doesn't look like the User-Agent string you have used in your question is that of a mobile client.

For example,

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19";

try {
    httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    // Add your data

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    // ....
} catch ... {
```

This should give you the mobile version of a page, as would be seen by a Galaxy Nexus device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of a ton of mobile browser user agent strings: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/

Maybe try a different user agent string like:

> Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/9 (Compatible; MSIE:9.0; iPhone; BlackBerry9700; AppleWebKit/24.746; U; en) Presto/2.5.25 Version/10.54